# Як правильно використовувати жіночу форму слова "байдужий"?

Tags: правопис, прикметники

Наче і зрозуміло - байдужий, байдужа. Але зустріла у Коцюбинського: "В останні часи вона почувала себе такою втомленою, такою апатичною, байдуж**н**ою до всього."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

СУМ визначає слово *байдужний*, як синонім до слова *байдужий*:

> ***БАЙДУ́ЖНИЙ***, а, е. Те саме, що байдужий 1. Згорда поглядають вони [чумаки] довкола, певні в своїх силах, байдужні до всяких життєвих незгод (Михайло Коцюбинський, I, 1955, 180); Він відвернувся, силкуючися надати свойому лицю згірдний і байдужний вигляд (Іван Франко, VII, 1951, 312); Знов [Рустам] присьорбнув чаю, куточком, ока простежив за Саїдом, який своєю байдужною мовчанкою починав лякати таджика (Іван Ле, Міжгір'я, 1953, 132).

**Отже слово *байдужна* є цілком нормативним для української мови, як і слово *байдужа***.